# Android page Controller navigation without touch

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I need to create page controller in android.

For that i have followed 1 very simple example [THIS IS LINK I HAVE USED](https://github.com/fabsimilian/Android-Swipe-view-with-pager/)

All thing is working good i need only i need to swip pages automatically without touch events....
How to make it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement on swipe logic in to Timer, and based on that swipe pages automatically without touch.

Comment: any useful link you know?